# Constant resolution inside EL variable

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I wonder if there is some solution for this problem:

- I'm using Spring MVC
- I'm having value for attribute where I store some object saved as constant
- I'd like to access model through that constant in JSP, so something like this:

`${ <%= ATTR_ALL_TEMPLATES %> }`

Don't worry, I don't want to use scriptlets, just for sake of clarification. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I want to communicate between Portlet/Servlet and JSP just by constants without the need to know what value they have. And so instead of `${ allMyTemplates }` I want to use something like stated above.

Comment: have you checked SpEL [Read here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Comment: You want to use constant in JSP page using EL ?

Comment: @sankrish does it contain some method to do so?

Comment: @Yagnesh I want to communicate between Portlet/Servlet and JSP jsut by constants without the need to know what value they have. And so instead of `${ allMyTemplates }` I want to use something like `${ <%= ATTR_ALL_TEMPLATES %> }`

Comment: `ATTR_ALL_TEMPLATES` is constant present in servlet ? or any other file ?

Comment: Yes, in Constants.java file.

Comment: See my answer below. may this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to read `Constant` from java constant file in jsp using EL.
There is one [Jakarta : Unstandard Tag library](http://people.apache.org/builds/jakarta-taglibs-sandbox/nightly/projects/unstandard/) which is used to read constant from java file.([Maven Repo.](http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/taglibs/taglibs-unstandard/20060829/))
Use  to read constant from java file.

You need to add jar file for that and include tag lib declaration in your JSP file as below :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0" prefix="un"%>
```

To read any constant you first need to include below line for particular java constant file for example :

```
<un:useConstants var="regStatus"com.example.YourConstantsClass"/>
```

Read constant by below line:

```
<p>${Constants.MY_CONSTANT_1}</p>
```

There [another tag library](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/Journal200601.jsp#a3) which provide same functionality.

May this will help you.